# Email Action Not appearing in Case Feed

Tags: page-layout, email2case

I have deliverability set to All Emails

I also have enabled email-to-case

What else could stop the email lightning action for showing on my cases?

This is a video of the problem.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_tH4zneKQTI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Have you added them on the layout?

Comment: Yes, and I confirmed it's the layout for my Sys Admin Profile.